# What kind of action does an Invocation take?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, actions

What kind of action is it to use invocations such as Armor of Shadows and Fiendish Vigor? Are they defined as action, bonus action or free action? The book doesn't clarify.

Answer (score 9):

If a feature lets you cast a spell, you use the casting time of that spell, unless stated otherwise. You just follow the general rules for the spell.

Note that *mage armor* has a duration of 8 hours and *false life* has a duration of 1 hour. Both can be cast well ahead of combat. Also beware that both invocations you list only allow the spell to be cast on yourself.